# In MongoDb is there a way to get last 1000 array elements from multiple documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, querying

Given the following Mongo document model:

[image: Document Model]

Each document in the collection represents 1 hour of resource monitoring. In each document, there is a collection of summaries. There is also a count of the number of summaries as an integer, as it may make life easier.

**Is there an efficient way to query the collection and return either just the recent most 1000 summaries as an aggregated list?**

**Or an efficient way to query the collection and return the number of documents that contain the recent most 1000 summaries?**

*The number of summaries in each document will differ, but the number of summaries in one single document will never equal more than 1000.*

EDIT: I should mention I am using mongo with the .NET driver so have LINQ available to me.

Comment: I have a couple of questions : Which version of MongoDB are you running ? And are you filtering the request on a certain date ? (ie: summaries for 26/9/2017)

Comment: I believe I am using version 3.4.7 and I am using csharp driver v2.4.4.0. I generally do filtering on the timestamp and have that indexed, I figured I could probably get a number of hours a check if there is 1000 summaries, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Mongo aggregation ? If you want to return the 1000 most recent summaries you could go with an $unwind followed by a $replaceRoot operation, here's the shell query I tried :

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{$match : {your timestamp match query here}},
{$sort : {"timestamp": -1}},
{$unwind : "$summaries"},
{$limit : 1000},
{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$summaries"}}
])
```

The match operation at the beginning of your aggregation pipeline is important as  indexes are only used at the first step. If you unwind your whole collection your performance might drop drastically.

Comment: Regarding your second question, what exactly do you want to return, the ids of the documents containing the first 1000 timestamps or just the number of documents ?

Comment: Ultimately I want a list of the recent most 1000 summaries.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow. Thanks for helping

Comment: OK just tested this in Robo and it works great... Now to figure out how to do it with the driver. Thanks for the help